# JavaScript to split string with whitespaces at the first comma and ignore the rest of string

Tags: javascript, split

**edit: thanks for the input on this, issue was that the initial input field received the string via google autocomplete, and on change wasnt working.... but when i changed it to on submit of form the string truncated as expected. great help and the solution below worked fine too, thanks.**

I really don't know why this isn't working, I have tested several variations found on here but isn't getting the full part of string.

I have a input field that is autocompleted with an address value separated into pieces with commas, i.e. "street value, city value, state and zip values, country value".

I am using an on change function to get each part into separate fields:

```js
jQuery('input[name="location"]').on("change", function() {
  var location = jQuery('input[name="location"]').val();
  var street = location.split(',')[0];
  jQuery('input[name="street"]').val(street);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But although the input field for "Street" should update with a value of, for example, "1234 Random Avenue", it returns only "1234" in the field. So it is for whatever reason truncating at the first whitespace in the string before the comma, rather than including everything before the first comma separator as wanted. I have tested using `[1]` but no difference... it doesn't return anything after the first whitespace rather than using the comma as specified as the separator to use....

Comment: What's the full address you're trying to input?

Comment: I've added a snippet with jQuery included. If you can [edit] your question, then edit the snippet by including the HTML on which the code functions (preferably with sample data), that would go a long way toward making this question more useful.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a little bit more the question?

Here is a Codepen working corretly as I understand with your code:

```js
jQuery('input[name="location"]').on("change", function() {
  var location = jQuery('input[name="location"]').val();
  var parts = location.split(',');
  
  if(parts.length >= 1){
    var street = parts[0];
    jQuery('input[name="street"]').val(street)
  }
  if(parts.length >= 2) {
    var house = parts[1];
    jQuery('input[name="house"]').val(house);
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="location" name="location">
<input type="text" placeholder="street" name="street">
<input type="text" placeholder="house" name="house">
```